# Parameterized SQL queries don't work

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I have posted this question already because I had problems with the "LIKE" statement but now I realized there are problems with parameterized statements at all. Here is my code:

for example when I write:

```
 sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT @cusId,@cusName FROM " + form1.getTable() + " WHERE @cusId LIKE @filter", connection);

 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cusId", form1.cusId.Text);
 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cusName", form1.cusName.Text);
 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("filter", form1.filterType().Trim() + "%");

 sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
            sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);
            form1.setDataGrid = datTable;
```

Somehow I always get

```
 "Must declare the scalar variable @..."
```

for each variable when I fill the data table. I tried that already with

```
 sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and it seems to work in this case (when I update a database it works fine) but I need to bind the values to my DataGridView.

EDIT: Even when I just try to write something like:

```
 ... WHERE cusId.Text = @cusId
```

I get the same error

Comment: Are your column names `cusId` and `cusName` or you try to parameterize them?

Comment: That are column names but even when I leave them out and just use the filter variable in different ways I get still the same error

Comment: What `form1.filterType().Trim()` returns exactly?

Comment: It returns the text from a textbox. Like I said. The ExecuteNonQuery works but the data tables not

Answer (score 1):

As noted, you aren't working with parameters quite right. Your SqlCommand should be something more like this:

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT cusId,cusName FROM " + form1.getTable() + " WHERE cusId LIKE @filter", connection);
```

Note how the columns you are trying to select aren't parameters (so don't include '@' symbol).

When you add parameters you DO need to add the '@' symbol. Something like this:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusId", form1.cusId.Text);
```

Comment: Yes I tried that now with the parameters and it shows me still the same error... even when I leave the column names like they are (directly grabed from textboxes)

Answer (score 0):

You can't parameterize your table and column names . You can *only* parameterize your values.

If you *really* wanna get your table and column names dynamically, you can use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table) but which is a bad idea.

Best way to get your column names dynamically is creating a strong validation for your column names or creating a black list for them.

Using `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't effect anything since it's because just execute your query, does not return any data. Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections, commands and adapter.

Here an example;

```
string str = string.Format("SELECT {0}, {1} FROM {2} WHERE {0} LIKE @filter",
                           form1.cusId.Text,
                           form1.cusName.Text,
                           form1.getTable());

sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(str, connection);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filter", form1.filterType().Trim() + "%");

sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);
```

But I have to say again, you *really* need strong validation or black list for your column and table name when you try get them outside of your program.

I used `AddWithValue` in this example but this method [*might* be dangerous in some cases](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Using `.Add()` overloads to specify it's db type and parameter size implicitly would be better.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know that and he accepted it. I still don't know what's wrong with the last value then... Can I use ExecuteNonQuery to fill a data table?

Comment: first parameter in AddWithValue method should also have at so it should  be like "@filter", and You can't use ExecuteNonQuery to fill a DataTable, SqlDataAdapter is correct way to achieve this.

Comment: Even when I use @filter I get the same error and when I try to simply use "= @cusId" I get the same so it doesn't work at all. Whats wrong with the datatable?

Comment: @ScorpX I added an example. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! I tried:

```
  using (sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection))
                {
                    sqlDatAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@filter", SqlDbType.Int, 25).Value = CusIdEnter;
                    sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);
                    form1.setDataGrid = datTable;
                }
```

and now it works! One had to bind the parameters to the Adapter